# entity translation access permission alter

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) for node translations.

I would like to modify access to edit form for this translation language based on roles and node properties. I've a field in the node entity with a select list of languages, translator should only access translate nodes in languages that are checked in that list.

Which is the best option to modify the access to the **node/{NID}/edit/{LANGUAGE}** ?

- `hook_menu_alter` ?
- `hook_node_access()`: this hook is called but how can I get the language? (`$_GET` could be problematic I think).
- Extending the `EntityTranslation` class?
- Other?

Comment: have you found any solution. If so that will be very helpful if you can share your solution here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how its working for me, with args() we can get path ie english or any other language node is there :

> Example Paths in my case:
>
> node/[nid]/edit/add/sv/en
>
> node/[nid]/edit/add/en/sv
>
> node/[nid]/edit/sv
>
> node/[nid]/edit/en

```
define('ROLE_EDITOR',4); // role ID 4
define('ROLE_EDITOR_ENGLISH',10); // role ID 10

function my_module_node_access($node,$op,$account) {
  global $user;

  if (in_array(ROLE_EDITOR, array_keys($user->roles)) && !in_array(ROLE_EDITOR_ENGLISH, array_keys($user->roles))) {
    if(arg(3)== "en"){
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
    if(arg(3) == "add" && arg(4) == "sv"){
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
  }

  if (!in_array(ROLE_EDITOR, array_keys($user->roles)) && in_array(ROLE_EDITOR_ENGLISH, array_keys($user->roles))) {
    if(arg(3)== "sv" || arg(3)== NULL){  // Null is need to add as edit and edit/sv is same in my case because sv is defult language 
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
    if(arg(3) == "add" && arg(4) == "en"){
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
  }


}
```